# Бесплатный деплой сайта

Tags: reactjs, flask, развертывание, deploy

Куда я могу задеплоить свой проект Flask + React + PostgresSql + CUDA?

Необходимо выложить на хостинг учебный проект, однако есть сложность в том, что там нейросеть, и она работает только с установленной CUDA.

Подскажите, пожалуйста бесплатные хостинги

Answer (score 0):

Через DynDNS хостить со своего компа если нет выделенного IP. Я крайне сильно сомневаюсь, что такое захостят бесплатно.